# Python Data Frame Lists - how to make number of elements in the array equal

Tags: python

I have a data frame with lists within list . Each list contains integer array elements  . Some of them having 2 element , some of the 3 . Is there a way in python to make the number of those elements equal by assiging any default value for those positions where there is no value as of now . For example , in below df,

```
AS IS

0                     [7542, 2313, 7538, 7554, 2313, 1234]
1                           [7816, 7554, 5083, 4959, 1234]
2     [7816, 7542, 7816, 7542, 7534, 7535, 7535, 7534]
3                              [7150, 7279, 7542, 5673]
4                                    [7816, 7542, 7542]
5                              [7542, 6712, 7542, 7542]
6                                    [7816, 7542, 7542]
7                              [7542, 1237, 6732, 7543]

To BE (by introducing default 0000 (or 0) to make this array structure symmetrc

0     [7542, 2313, 7538, 7554, 2313, 1234, 0000, 0000]
1     [7816, 7554, 5083, 4959, 1234, 0000, 0000, 0000]
2     [7816, 7542, 7816, 7542, 7534, 7535, 7535, 7534]
3     [7150, 7279, 7542, 5673, 0000, 0000, 0000, 0000]
4     [7816, 7542, 7542, 0000, 0000, 0000, 0000, 0000]
5     [7542, 6712, 7542, 7542, 0000, 0000, 0000, 0000]
```

Is there a way to manipulate df lists to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

With pure Python, you can get the maximum list length in your nested list, and then pad each entry with enough `0000` elements to match the maximum length.

```
max_n = max([len(x) for x in data])
[x+['0000']*(max_n - len(x)) for x in data]
```

Output:

```
[[7542, 2313, 7538, 7554, 2313, 1234, '0000', '0000'],
 [7816, 7554, 5083, 4959, 1234, '0000', '0000', '0000'],
 [7816, 7542, 7816, 7542, 7534, 7535, 7535, 7534],
 [7150, 7279, 7542, 5673, '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000'],
 [7816, 7542, 7542, '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000'],
 [7542, 6712, 7542, 7542, '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000'],
 [7816, 7542, 7542, '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000'],
 [7542, 1237, 6732, 7543, '0000', '0000', '0000', '0000']]
```

Another way: With Pandas, you can use [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.fillna("0000")
      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
0  7542  2313  7538  7554  2313  1234  0000  0000
1  7816  7554  5083  4959  1234  0000  0000  0000
2  7816  7542  7816  7542  7534  7535  7535  7534
3  7150  7279  7542  5673  0000  0000  0000  0000
4  7816  7542  7542  0000  0000  0000  0000  0000
5  7542  6712  7542  7542  0000  0000  0000  0000
6  7816  7542  7542  0000  0000  0000  0000  0000
7  7542  1237  6732  7543  0000  0000  0000  0000
```

You can use `.values` to shift out of the `DataFrame` object type, if needed.  `df.fillna("0000").values` will result in a nested list.

Data:

```
data = [[7542, 2313, 7538, 7554, 2313, 1234],
        [7816, 7554, 5083, 4959, 1234],
        [7816, 7542, 7816, 7542, 7534, 7535, 7535, 7534],
        [7150, 7279, 7542, 5673],
        [7816, 7542, 7542],
        [7542, 6712, 7542, 7542],
        [7816, 7542, 7542],
        [7542, 1237, 6732, 7543]]
```

Note: It's not totally clear whether you actually need a 4-zero string (`'0000'`) - if not, you can just replace `'0000'` with `0` (an integer) where it appears in this solution.  Using the integer `0` will allow for a consistent data type throughout each individual row/list.

Comment: While trying python without pandas I am encountering this message ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')